Why am I getting a Tuple mismatch error when unpacking the return of RandomUnderSampler from imbalanced-learn?
I am using RandomUnderSampler from imbalanced-learn (ver. 0.12.3).
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

# df = some pandas DataFrame

X_train, y_train = RandomUnderSampler(
    sampling_strategy=0.1,
    random_state=1234,
    replacement=False,
).fit_resample(df.drop("target", axis=1), df["target"])

I am getting the following error:
Expression with type "tuple[Unknown | DataFrame | ... | Series[Unknown], Unknown | DataFrame | ... | Series[Unknown]] | tuple[Unknown | DataFrame | ... | Series[Unknown], Unknown | DataFrame | ... | Series[Unknown], Unknown]" cannot be assigned to target tuple
  Type "tuple[Unknown | DataFrame | ... | Series[Unknown], Unknown | DataFrame | ... | Series[Unknown], Unknown]" is incompatible with target tuple
    Tuple size mismatch; expected 2 but received 3 Pylance(reportAssignmentType)

The code works, but the error is bugging me. What seems to be the problem with my code?

Are you sure you know where the error is caused? Try separating the df.drop into its own variable, as well the RandomUnderSampler call.

I tried separating df.drop("target", axis=1) and df["target"] into their own variables. I also tried creating the RandomUnderSampler into its own variable. I am still getting red underlines in X_train, y_train.

It does work. What's weird is that Pylance also raises an error in sampling_strategy=0.1 citing "float" is incompatible with "str".

@dbkoop That's not weird at all. It's because RandomUnderSampler does not have type hinting. The default value for sampling_strategy is "auto". Therefore, without any information to the contrary, Pylance believes that the only legal type is str. Please show code that works. What you've shown in the question is not runnable. We need a Minimal Reproducible Example

@SIGHUP I tried exactly copying the sample code from RandomUnderSampler docs, and I am still getting the same error despite it working. I'm guessing this is more a problem of Pylance than RandomUnderSampler.

There is no explicit type hinting for RandomUnderSampler. fit_resample() returns a 2-tuple. However, the underlying code could return tuples of array-like, dataframe or sparse matrix. See documentation The use of typing.Any is generally frowned upon. However, you could suppress this Pylance warning as follows:
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
import pandas as pd
from typing import Any

df = pd.DataFrame() # Obviously nonsensical. Just here to demonstrate how the Pylance warning can be suppressed

t: tuple[Any, ...] = RandomUnderSampler(
    sampling_strategy=0.1, # type: ignore
    random_state=1234,
    replacement=False,
).fit_resample(df.drop("target", axis=1), df["target"])


t[0] # X_train
t[1] # y_train

